# For what is "downloadable_domains" in env.php file?

Tags: magento2

For what is "downloadable_domains" in env.php file? I have read on Magento dev docs, but I can`t understand where it is used? Please do not add links to dev docs. Describe please your point of view.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you are creating Downloadable Product(s), you are setting a link/url to download particular File/Resource.

[image]

The domain name of this link/url **must be white-listed** and to do so, you need to add this domain name in `env.php` file under "downloadable_domains".

**Listing the CLI commands to manage "downloadable_domains" :**

To add a domain :

```
bin/magento downloadable:domains:add www.mydomain.com
```

To remove a domain :

```
bin/magento downloadable:domains:remove www.mydomain.com
```

To list all whitelisted domains :

```
bin/magento downloadable:domains:show
```

Comment: super, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the issue like (Link URL's domain is not in list of downloadable_domains in env.php) which is solved by doing this suggestion

Thank you very much :)